# EF DbContext how to isolate domain objects and avoid auto-generated code issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

DB context is auto-generated in EF. That s great but how do I prevent it from 
erasing my domain class inclusions? Any tricks?

```
namespace EFContext
{
    using xxx.DomainObjects;//<---------------------------------- here
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class EFContextContainer : DbContext

// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
```

Answer (score 1):

Create partial EFContextContainer in another file and include the namespace there.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe my domain objects need to be known in the generated class though. (DBSets<domainobjects>).

Comment: Found my answer, in the file used for generation (.tt) there is a section with accessible inclusion instructions. Have added my domain include there. works. Thanks

Comment: Haven't know about that. Could you add answer with short info about it? People looking for this question would find if handy.